# What is Application Insight in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-application-insights

I can see number in thousand as Application Insights in Visual Studio 2017. I read about the Application Insights but does not exactly understood what is use of it.

As shown in below screenshot, its showing 25K in Application Insights and continuously increasing. `Messaging_TestApp` is SQL Database name used for NService bus.

Can anyone explain what is Application Insights and why number increasing ?

[image]

Comment: @TomTom Thanks for your prediction, but I have spent hours to understand why ```Application Insights``` number increasing without any reason. I would greatly pleased if anyone help me to understand the same. I am concern, Is this degrading the performance of the application as its huge number.

Comment: @TomTom I think the question title might be throwing you a little here. The second half of his question regarding what it is in the context of visual studio and what the number represents seems like the gist of what he is asking.

Comment: Well, what throwms me off is that " I read about the Application Insights but does not exactly understood what is use of it." which is on the level of "do restaurants serve food?". How can one spend more than 10 secnds reading about AI without - getting into the overview document in the documentation that explains what it does?

Comment: @TomTom Why don't you focus on what he ask?

Comment: @TomTom probably because he came at it from the very narrow querying scope of what it's doing inside visual studio, saw a whole bunch of stuff that didn't really seem to apply to what he was seeing and got confused.

Answer (score 7):

**First, let me answer the basic "What is App Insights?":**

Application insights is essentially an activity monitoring tool from Microsoft for any type of application.

From Microsoft's documentation on [What is Application Insights?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-overview)

> Application Insights is an extensible Application Performance Management (APM) service for web developers on multiple platforms. Use it to monitor your live web application. It will automatically detect performance anomalies. It includes powerful analytics tools to help you diagnose issues and to understand what users actually do with your app. It's designed to help you continuously improve performance and usability. It works for apps on a wide variety of platforms including .NET, Node.js and J2EE, hosted on-premises or in the cloud. It integrates with your DevOps process, and has connection points to a variety of development tools. It can monitor and analyze telemetry from mobile apps by integrating with Visual Studio App Center.

**Now, the more specific parts of your question:**

**What you are seeing in Visual Studio?**

Application insights is normally run on a server sitting somewhere or purchased as a service from Azure, but it was recently also built into Visual Studio for monitoring apps running out of the IDE. The VS IDE is essentially running a sort of minified version of Application Insights that has then hooked into the SQL Database project you are currently debugging.

**What is the Banner number?**

From my own testing this number appears to be the total number of telemetry logs Application Insights has recorded since I started the application. Perhaps most of them are being filtered out by your 30m time range. 
[image]

Comment: @RedWei As far as I know, your source code isn't sent to Application Insights. Your stack traces can be and some basic data about what projects you have and their dependencies are sent to app insights . So..... even if Microsoft was an allegedly big evil spying giant who are (maybe??) breaking their user agreements they can't get a whole lot of data really.

Comment: From this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-windows-desktop. They said "The only limitation is the need to allow communication to the Application Insights service" which means AI is always online which is shady.

Comment: [One of article says](https://stackify.com/application-insights-things-to-know/) : If your code uses dynamic SQL, Application Insights will collect the full query and upload it to Azure. This means if the query contained personal information, credit card numbers, or anything else that could be sensitive, it is getting uploaded from your server to Microsoft.

Another thing to know on this topic, App Insights never collects SQL parameters.

Comment: @D_K That's very good point, I forgot about queries. I stand corrected. :)

Comment: Oh, and if you hook up a logging library like log4net and then hook that into app insights it's also possible that important data could slip in there.

Comment: Unless you've configured application insights to **SEND** data to Azure (you'd have to sign into azure, create a resource, etc), then the information you're seeing above is only during the *current debugger session*, and is *local only*, and never left your box.  you can check this by right clicking the project and finding the "Configure Application Insights" menu item in the context menu, or possibly in the "Add" submenu if you've never added AI yourself.

Comment: You can also see it in the output windows, where you should see lines like "Application Insights (unconfigured)" in the output window.  those are the things that get processed to create the search window above.